# Difference between aws mv & aws cp object

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, http, object, amazon-s3

I have two commands in aws cli

aws s3 cp test1 s3://buckettest1 
 &
aws s3 mv test_data s3://buckettest1

Seems that both do HTTP PUT request to s3 server & adds object to my bucket. What differs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like `cp` and `mv` commands differ in any other platform.

`aws cp` will copy a local file or S3 object to another location locally or in S3.

`aws mv` will move a local file or S3 object to another location locally or in S3, i.e. it will delete it from source and put it on the target path.